# Use Facebook SDK For Invitation Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to use the Android SDK to "invite friends', however my code is giving the following error...

> "failed to find provider info for
>   com.facebook.katana.provider.attributionid"

Could you please review my code below and help me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

appLinkUrl = "your app link url";
previewImageUrl = "https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg";

if (AppInviteDialog.canShow())
{
    AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
            .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
            .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
            .build();

    AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(MainActivity.this);
    appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e)
        {
        }
    });

    appInviteDialog.show(content);
}
```

Comment: That is an innocuous error and is not related to the invite dialog at all. Are you seeing the dialog pop up at all?

Comment: no i can`t see it because when I use else statement with program flow is going to go through it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Are you saying that "canShow()" is returning false? That generally means that the Facebook app you have doesn't support the dialog. What version of the Facebook app do you have, and what device type are you testing on?

Comment: Z2 With latest facebook app version